# Making a div use all the space available in a container

Tags: html, css

I have this container div with two elements:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="right">Some, list, of, words, that, I, use</div>
    <div id="left">Person Name</div>
</div>​
```

And I want to make the **#right** div use up the space that is left by the **#left** div and hide the overflow.

Please also note that the **#left** div width is variable.

I came up with this css so far:

```
#container {
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}

#left {
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px dotted #ccc;
    display: inline;
}

#right {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px dotted #ddd;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}
```

​
But the **#right** div still shows all text and end up on the following line, like displayed below:

[image: Sample result]

I played with making the **#right** div not float, adding `width: 100%` but nothing seems to work...

Does anyone know how I can make both be displayed on the same line, but making the **#right** div have its overflow hidden?

jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/y4xnx/13/

**Edit:** fixed my explanation of which divs should do what.

Comment: You might like to revise your explanation, specifically "I want to make the #right div use up the space that is left by the #right div".

Comment: Thanks @Marcel, see if it's better now.

Comment: Are you able to put **#left** before **#right** in your html?

Comment: Yes, I am able to do that @grc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would help to put **#left** before **#right**:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">Person Name</div>
    <div id="right">Some, list, of, words, that, I, use</div>
</div>​
```

Then a few changes in the css should do what you're wanting:

```
#left {
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: 1px dotted #ccc;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#right {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px dotted #ddd;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/grc4/MvXuN/

Answer (score 1):

I tried to achieve whatever I understood from your question. Check the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/y4xnx/20/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
     <div id="left">Person Name</div>
    <div id="right">Some, list, of, words, that, I, use</div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#left {
    border: 1px dotted #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
}

#right {
    display:inline-block;
    border: 1px dotted #ddd;
}
​
```